# SQLAlchemy HSTORE column not overriding DB default

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, hstore

Given that I create a database like this

- `createuser -s test`
- `createdb test -O test`
- `psql test -c "create extension hstore; create table data_table(id int, data hstore)"`

And given that I have the following code

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from sqlalchemy import Table, Integer, create_engine, MetaData, Column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import HSTORE as _HSTORE
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableDict


metadata = MetaData()


class HSTORE(_HSTORE):

    def result_processor(self, dialect, coltype):
        processor = super(HSTORE, self).result_processor(dialect, coltype)
        def process(value):
            return processor(value) or {}  # force a default
        return process


engine = create_engine('postgresql://test:test@localhost/test')


data_table = Table('data_table', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('data', HSTORE)
)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(
        data_table.insert(),
        data = None
    )

    _, data = conn.execute(data_table.select()).fetchone()

assert data is not None
```

I would expect the `HSTORE.result_processor` method to be called and apply a default is the value is None. However, it never seems to occur and the assert statement raises an exception. How do I intercept the value from the database and tweak it to whatever I want it to be?

This is with python 2.7, postgres 9.3 and SQLAlchemy 8.4 and 9.0.

Answer (score 4):

Bah, shortly after a better Google search found [a correct implementation](http://pieceofpy.com/2011/10/12/sqlalchemy-custom-types-integers-datetime/).

Apparently I should have used a TypeDecorator rather than trying to do this directly on the type (tho the reason why still escapes me).

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import HSTORE as _HSTORE

class HSTORE(types.TypeDecorator):

    impl = _HSTORE

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return value or {}
```

Works as expected.